# Test Clonezilla image recovery

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, virtualbox, backup, clonezilla

I have successfully created a backup image of my laptop's hard drive using CloneZilla. Before making system changes I want to verify that the backup is fully restorable and can be booted from.

I have successfully restored the image to an external USB drive and tried booting from that, however it always seems to load the copy of windows 8.1 from the local disk (to check, I made a simple change to the desktop background after the backup operation). I have tried disabling the boot option in the BIOS for the local disk but I suspect it is reading the <s>MBR</s> GPT boot information from the external drive, then using that information to load the file system on the local disk (please correct that assumption if it's wrong) There is no option in the BIOS to disable the local disk entirely.

I then tried booting from the external disk on an isolated PC and I get a blinking cursor (HAL/Driver problem?)

I've also tried using VirtualBox to boot from the USB device using both;

- a restore of the backup image
- and a disk-to-disk clone

Both of these result in a "no bootable medium found" message from VirtualBox.

Clearly I don't want to perform an actual restore to the local disk, in case the backup isn't fully functional.

How can I test that the CloneZilla backup I've created is recoverable in a safe environment?

**Update**

Starting afresh, I recovered the backup image to the external drive again. When plugging it in Disk Manager reports an error

> The disk is offline because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online

Here's what it looks like when the disk is brought online.

[image: Disk Manager Screenshot]

I wonder if the "Bring Online" operation is causing partition flags to be lost? If that's not the case then shouldn't CloneZilla be replicating these attributes as part of the backup?

Comment: Presumably disconnecting the laptop's drive - if accessible - also results in a "not bootable" error similar to the isolated systems? (still, good question)

Comment: Unfortunately the drive is not accessible without loosening a few screws, since this is a brand new laptop I'd rather not void the warranty just yet, especially without a verified backup! :)

Comment: Quite sensible! Though unless the screws are sealed I wouldn't have thought it would be a warranty-voiding process... but don't trust me on this! Have you examined the disk-to-disk clone with something like `diskpart` or similar too see if the partition's `boot flag` is set?

Comment: I've not used `diskpart` but I have just noticed in Disk Management the primary partition on the original disk is marked with both "Wim Boot" and "Boot" whereas the clone is flagged only with "Wim Boot"

Comment: Using `diskpart` the relevant volume is *not* marked as boot, how do I fix that?

Comment: The dog ate my homework, or in this case; the `PrtScrn` key causes my computer to lock up (reproducibly). No screenshots I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 0):

The "not a bootable disk" on the clones makes it sound as though the `boot` flag hasn't been set on that.

### How do I check if the boot flag is set?

Good question. [`diskpart`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is your friend:

1. Start a regular command prompt and run `diskpart` from that; or you can run `diskpart` from the Start menu or `diskpart.exe` directly. It will ask for admin access.
2. `list volume` will list volumes and their flags. The `boot` flag show up under the `info` column:

   [image: diskpart screenshot]

   Here you can see my `C:` volume has the boot flag set, but the removable drive (`E:`)<sup>1</sup> does not.

### How to set `boot` flag on partition using `bootsect`

So, let's assume your backup image is accessible (but not bootable) under the letter `E:`, you can verify the files are there but see that it's not got the bootflag set using `diskpart`. well, you can use [`bootsect`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824948.aspx) to set the boot flag<sup>2</sup>.

1. Start an administrative command prompt from the <kbd>Win+x</kbd> (Power User Menu)
2. `G:`
3. `cd boot`
4. `bootsect /nt60 G:`

Done!

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* that's a Debian `netinst` partition...

<sup>2</sup> or switch between old style ( < Vista) and newer; see the [Technet 
page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824948.aspx) for more info

Comment: `Updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.  The update may be unreliable since the volume could not be locked during the update: Access is denied.` restarted and checked `diskpart` still no boot flag :(

Comment: @RedTaz make sure nothing is accessing the drive (or open Explorer windows etc); and/or add the `/force` flag (at your own risk!)

Comment: Correction to the above. Using the `/force` option reports a successful operation, however, reboot & check `diskpart` the elusive boot flag is still missing

Comment: How strange. Is it marked `boot` before reboot in `diskpart`? Is it an `active` partition?

Comment: Using a fresh copy of the clone, the `bootsect` reports success, immediately after `diskpart` still reports no flags for that volume

Comment: Can you use `diskpart` and run `active` after selecting the partiton, before using `bootsect`? Very strange issue, I may add in a section on GParted as that's more likely to succeed; wanted to keep it in the windows family of tools for consistency!

Comment: `The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks` this is a GPT partition (question text edited to remove MBR reference)